# What privileges are needed to run EXPLAIN PLAN FOR CREATE INDEX?

Tags: index, permissions, oracle-11g, explain

My user can `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` any query I like, but not for `CREATE INDEX`. I need to do that in order to estimate a suggested index's size, and using `sysdba` is out of question. What privileges should I ask for? This is Oracle 11.2.0.3.

```
SQL> explain plan for create index INDEXNAME on SOMEONE.SOMETABLE("FLD1","FLD2");
explain plan for create index INDEXNAME on SOMEONE.SOMETABLE("FLD1","FLD2")
                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL> explain plan for select * from SOMEONE.SOMETABLE order by fld1 desc;

Explained.

SQL>
```

Comment: Does your user have privileges to create an index on the `someone.sometable` table?  Is that a table in a different schema or in your schema?

Comment: You might also see if you have privileges on the `dbms_space.create_index_cost` function which estimates the size of an index http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_space.htm#i1002659

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely in you not having sufficient privileges to create the index in question -- nothing to do with `EXPLAIN PLAN` itself.

To quote [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF01209), "To create an index in another schema, you must have the CREATE ANY INDEX system privilege".